# Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, geckodriver

I have to deploy a flask app to use firefox geckodriver in production server . The server is simple ubuntu 18.04 with nginx installed . The application is a imageDetection flask python application . In the server "localhost:5000" the application works perfectly but on domain or live "127.0.0.1:80" it says "**Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.**" .

in terminal -> whereis geckodriver
geckodriver: /usr/bin/geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver /home/administator/.local/bin/geckodriver

here /home/administator is my default user

geckodriver is installed with "**chmod +x geckodriver**"

- selenium = 3.141.0
- geckodriver = 0.26.0
- firefox = 76.0.1
- python = 3.6

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

This is very simple download the geckodriver.exe for your OS from Google. And then put it in the directory you are working in.

**For Chrome**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
```

**For Firefox**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox('./geckodriver')
```

*Download the Geckodriver for your OS and put it in the same directory as your python3 file with the above code. If you have chrome in your PC and not firefox than go for chromedriver.*

Download from here Geckodriver;

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: I have tried as you said .. but now the message is Message:" Unable to find a matching set of capabilities "

Comment: the problem is the geckodriver works perfectly fine on localhost:5000 but it shows error when run localhost:80 or 127.0.0.1 ......... other then that the application runs fine.....

Answer (score 0):

(I would have put this in a comment, but well, I can't comment :/)

Enable logging with Selenium and see in detail what it's trying to do.
Putting geckodriver in the working directory causes a host of other issues in my experience...

You can enable logging like this (assuming Python):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('selenium')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler( 'selenium.log' )
logger.addHandler(handler)
logging.getLogger('selenium.webdriver.remote').setLevel(logging.WARN)
logging.getLogger('selenium.webdriver.common').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Also, does your USER (the one that launches the flask application) have privileges to execute `geckodriver`? I mean, presumably, the `chmod +x geckodriver` would have covered that, but just for kicks, check the permissions.

Another thing: print out the contents of `$PATH` **in the script before you launch selenium** (this is possible with `os.environ` or something similar, I believe). It is somehow possible `$PATH` is being overwritten...

Also, I see you have THREE geckodrivers (/usr/bin, /usr/local/bin, & /home/administrator/...). Are those symlinked to each other? Or are they SEPARATE geckodrivers? I would use one geckodriver and make the rest links if you want, but honestly having one location (maybe /usr/local/bin) would make things more consistent across users.

One final thing: you mention that when you host the server on a different port (5000 vs 80), the error occurs (because presumably `localhost` maps to 127.0.0.1). Hosting the app on port 80 would require `sudo`, no? That would change the environment, perhaps? Maybe check `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

I hope that helps a bit...